# How to know that form submission did not encounter errors in this case?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I want to make something like a jQuery-Mobile app by putting many `div`s inside my page. So when I want to show a particular "screen" then I hide everything and after that I show the corresponding `div`. Now I want to set the `innerHtml` of a particular `div` to a `form` : so there is a button for the submission of it ; but it is not a real button but a `div` with a `class` "button" so that it appears like a `button`. Now in my page I manually coded the form submission when clicking the pseudo "submission-button". Untill now everything is ok about the mandatory fields ! My problem is when every mandatory fields are filled then I want to execute an ajax instead of submitting the form , because I want the screen to remain on the same screen. Here is what I have attempted :

```
{% include "header.phtml" %}

<div id="choix_type_reservation" class="tile-area padding10">
    <div class="tile-container">
        <div id="choix_salles" class="tile-large bg-crimson fg-white">
            <div class="tile-content">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <div class="frame"><img src="<?php echo HTTP_IMG ?>salle.jpg"/></div>
                    <div class="tile-label header fg-black">Salles</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="choix_tables" class="tile-large bg-darkPink fg-white">
            <div class="tile-content">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <div class="frame"><img src="<?php echo HTTP_IMG ?>table.png"/></div>
                    <div class="tile-label header fg-black">Tables</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="liste_salles" class="tile-area padding10">
    <div style="font-size:20px;"><a href="#" data-role="icon-retour"><span class="mif-arrow-left icon"></span></a></div><br />
    <div class="tile-container">
        <div class="header fg-white">Salles</div>
        <?php
        $t_salle = new Salle();
        $salles = $t_salle->lireParCritere([]);
        foreach ($salles as $salle) {
        ?>
        <div id="salle_<?php echo $salle->salle_code; ?>" data-pk="<?php echo $salle->salle_code; ?>" class="tile-square bg-crimson fg-white">
            <div class="tile-content">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <div class="frame"><img src="<?php echo HTTP_IMG ?>salle.jpg"/></div>
                    <div class="tile-label header fg-cyan"><b><?php echo $salle->salle_lib; ?></b></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="liste_tables" class="grid condensed">
    <div style="font-size:20px;"><a href="#" data-role="icon-retour"><span class="mif-arrow-left icon"></span></a></div><br />
    <div class="row cells4">
        <div class="cell"><span class="header">Salle</span></div>
        <div class="cell colspan3"><span class="header">Tables</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cells4">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="grid condensed">
                <?php
                $t_salle = new Salle();
                $salles = $t_salle->lireParCritere([]);
                foreach ($salles as $key => $salle) {
                ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">
                        <div id="tile_salle_<?php echo $key; ?>" data-pk="<?php echo $salle->salle_code; ?>" class="tile-square fg-white">
                            <div class="tile-content">
                                <div class="image-container">
                                    <div class="frame"><img src="<?php echo HTTP_IMG ?>salle.jpg"/></div>
                                    <div class="tile-label header fg-cyan"><?php echo $salle->salle_lib; ?></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell colspan3">
            <div id="tables"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="liste_reservations_salle" class="tile-area padding10"></div>

<div id="frmReservationSalle"></div> // this is the div which will contain the form

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" language="javascript">

    var previous_screen = [];

    function listerTables(salle_code) {

        var donne = "salle_code="+salle_code;

        var ret = $.ajax({
                data: donne,
                type: "POST",
                url:  "RestaurantReservation/ajaxListerTablesDansSalle",
                async: false
             }).responseText;

        $('#tables').html(ret);
    }

    function listerReservationsSalle(salle_code) {

        var donne = "salle_code="+salle_code;

        var salle_lib = $.ajax({
                data: donne,
                type: "POST",
                url:  "RestaurantReservation/ajaxGetSalleLib",
                async: false
             }).responseText;
        salle_lib = $.trim(salle_lib);

        donne += "&titre=Réservations pour la salle \""+salle_lib+"\"";

        var ret = $.ajax({
                data: donne,
                type: "POST",
                url:  "RestaurantReservation/ajaxGenerateListReservationSalle",
                async: false
             }).responseText;

        $('#liste_reservations_salle').show();
        $('#liste_reservations_salle').html(ret);

    }

    function afficherFrmReservationSalle(salle_code, mode) { // this will show the form

        var donne = "salle_code="+salle_code;

        var salle_lib = $.ajax({
                            data: donne,
                            type: "POST",
                            url:  "RestaurantReservation/ajaxGetSalleLib",
                            async: false
                         }).responseText;
        salle_lib = $.trim(salle_lib);

        if (mode == "ajout") {
            donne += "&titre=Ajout réservation de la salle \""+salle_lib+"\"";
        } else {
            donne += "&titre=Modification réservation de la salle \""+salle_lib+"\"";
        }

        donne += "&mode="+mode+"&action=RestaurantReservation/reserverSalleExec";

        var ret = $.ajax({
                data: donne,
                type: "POST",
                url:  "RestaurantReservation/ajaxFrmReservationSalle",
                async: false
             }).responseText;

        $('#frmReservationSalle').show();
        $('#frmReservationSalle').html(ret); // the div contains the form now
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#cell-content > div").hide(); // hide everything first ( content-page )

        $("#choix_type_reservation").show();

        /**
        *
        *    CHOICE OF RESERVATION
        *
        **/
        $("#choix_type_reservation").on("click", "div[id='choix_salles']", function(){
            previous_screen.push("#choix_type_reservation");
            $("#cell-content > div").hide();
            $("#liste_salles").show();
        });
        $("#choix_type_reservation").on("click", "div[id='choix_tables']", function(){
            previous_screen.push("#choix_type_reservation");
            $("#cell-content > div").hide();
            $("#liste_tables").show();
            $("#tile_salle_0").css("outline","#999999 solid 3px"); // "sélectionner" la première salle
            listerTables($("#tile_salle_0").attr("data-pk")); // lister les tables de la première salle
        });

        /**
        *
        *    LIST TABLES OF A ROOM
        *
        **/
        $("#liste_tables").on("click", "div[id^='tile_salle_']", function(){ // click a room to display its tables
            $("#tile_salle_0").css("outline","0");
            listerTables($(this).attr("data-pk"));
        });

        /**
        *
        *    LIST RESERVATIONS OF A ROOM
        *
        **/
        $("#liste_salles").on("click", "div[id^='salle_']", function() {
            $("#cell-content > div").hide();
            previous_screen.push("#liste_salles");
            listerReservationsSalle($(this).attr("data-pk"));
        });

        /**
        *
        *   BACK SCREEN MANAGEMENT
        *
        **/
        $("div").on("click", "a[data-role='icon-retour']", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $("#cell-content > div").hide();
            $(previous_screen.pop()).show();
        });
        $("div").on("click", "div[id='btn_retour']", function(e) { // back "pseudo-button" from form
            e.stopPropagation();
            $("#cell-content > div").hide();
            $(previous_screen.pop()).show();
        });

        /**
        *
        *   opening the form
        *
        **/
        $("div").on("click", "a[data-role='icon-add']", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $("#cell-content > div").hide();
            if ($(this).attr("data-target") == "formReservationSalle") {
                previous_screen.push("#liste_reservations_salle");
                afficherFrmReservationSalle($(this).attr("data-pk"), "ajout");
            } else {
                ...
            }
        });

        /**
        *
        *   validating form
        *
        **/
        $("div").on("click", "div[id='btn_ok']", function(e) { // pseudo-button in the form
            e.stopPropagation();
            $("form").submit(); // it is OK : form is not submitted if there are unfilled mandatory fields
        });

    });
</script>
{% include "footer.phtml" %}
```

Code of the form :

```
<form id="formulaireReservationSalle" name="formulaireReservationSalle"  method="POST" data-role="validator">
    <?php if (isset($data)) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" id="identifiant" name="identifiant" value="<?php echo isset($data) ? $data[0]->identifiant : ''; ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="hidden" id="salle_code" name="salle_code" value="<?php echo $salle_code; ?>" />
    <div class="flex-grid padding10">
        <div class="row"><div class="cell colspan12 margin10 header"><?php echo htmlentities($titre); ?></div></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell margin10">
                <div class="input-control modern select required">
                    <select name="clt_id" id="clt_id" data-validate-func="required" data-validate-hint="Ce champ est obligatoire">
                        <option value=""> -- S&eacute;lectionner un client -- </option>
                        <?php
                            $t_tabl = new Client();
                            $clients = $t_tabl->lireParCritere([]);
                            foreach ($clients as $client) {
                              $selected = (isset($data) && $client->clt_id == $data[0]->clt_id ? "selected" : "");
                              ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $client->clt_id; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $client->noms; ?></option>
                              <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell margin10">
                <div class="input-control modern text required" data-role="input" id="date_deb">
                    <input type="text" name="date_debut" id="date_debut" data-validate-func="required" data-validate-hint="Ce champ est obligatoire" value="<?php echo isset($data) ? convertDateFormat3($data[0]->date_debut,'/') : ''; ?>" placeholder="Date d&eacute;but"/>
                    <span class="label">Date d&eacute;but</span>
                    <button class="button helper-button clear"><span class="mif-cross"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell margin10">
                <div class="input-control modern text required" data-role="input">
                    <input type="text" name="heure_debut" id="heure_debut" value="<?php echo isset($data) ? $data[0]->hdeb : ''; ?>" placeholder="Heure d&eacute;but"/>
                    <span class="label">Heure d&eacute;but</span>
                    <button class="button helper-button clear"><span class="mif-cross"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell margin10">
                <div class="input-control modern text" data-role="input" id="date_fin">
                    <input type="text" name="date_fin" id="date_fin" data-validate-func="required" data-validate-hint="Ce champ est obligatoire" value="<?php echo isset($data) ? convertDateFormat3($data[0]->date_fin,'/') : ''; ?>" placeholder="Date fin"/>
                    <span class="label">Date fin</span>
                    <button class="button helper-button clear"><span class="mif-cross"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell margin10">
                <div class="input-control modern text" data-role="input">
                    <input type="text" name="heure_fin" id="heure_fin" value="<?php echo isset($data) ? $data[0]->hfin : ''; ?>" placeholder="Heure fin"/>
                    <span class="label">Heure fin</span>
                    <button class="button helper-button clear"><span class="mif-cross"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell margin10">
                <div class="input-control modern textarea">
                    <textarea name="commentaire" id="commentaire" placeholder="Commentaire..."><?php echo isset($data) ? $data[0]->commentaire : ''; ?></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row input-control"></div>
        <div class="row flex-just-sa">
            <div class="cell margin10">
                <div id="btn_ok" class="button default">Valider</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell margin10">
                <div id="btn_retour" class="button default">Annuler</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#date_deb").datepicker();

        $("#heure_debut").datetimepicker({
            datepicker:false,
            format:'H:i',
            step:5
        });

        $("#date_fin").datepicker();

        $("#heure_fin").datetimepicker({
            datepicker:false,
            format:'H:i',
            step:5
        });

    });
</script>
```

So how to know that the submission succeded in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `submit` callback. If like you said, the mandatory fields are being checked properly but your problem is that the form itself is submitted when all the data is valid, you can just:

```
$("#formulaireReservationSalle").submit(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     if(formIsValid()) {
          //AJAX Call.
     }
});

function formIsValid() {
     //Your validation code here.
     //Return true if all information is valid.
}
```

Comment: inside the form's document.ready or the main page's document.ready ?

Comment: The form's document one.

Comment: Then what I would suggest is to wrap your form's validation code inside a function and have it returning true or false. Depending on the return you would make the AJAX request or not.

Comment: so when to return true and when false ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88270/discussion-between-i-suck-at-programming-and-pheromix).

Comment: can you edit your answer because I dont have time to chat ?